Created New MSSQL Instance, Can't Execute Commands
I created a new MSSQL instance following the steps from this video. My purpose is to teach my students how to attack an MSSQL instance from a Linux machine, however I cannot execute a single command on the server when I connect.
I've tried using impacket-mssqlclient and sqsh to connect to the server, and the connection succeeds, however I get no output in my queries.
For instance, the below is me connecting to the local MSSQL server via impacket-mssqlclient and executing SELECT statements for enumeration.
# impacket-mssqlclient "sa":"Password1"@192.168.68.139
Impacket v0.12.0.dev1+20231114.165227.4b56c18 - Copyright 2023 Fortra

[*] Encryption required, switching to TLS
[*] ENVCHANGE(DATABASE): Old Value: master, New Value: master
[*] ENVCHANGE(LANGUAGE): Old Value: , New Value: us_english
[*] ENVCHANGE(PACKETSIZE): Old Value: 4096, New Value: 16192
[*] INFO(SQL02): Line 1: Changed database context to 'master'.
[*] INFO(SQL02): Line 1: Changed language setting to us_english.
[*] ACK: Result: 1 - Microsoft SQL Server (160 3232)
[!] Press help for extra shell commands
SQL (sa  dbo@master)> SELECT SYSTEM_USER;
SQL (sa  dbo@master)> SELECT @@VERSION;
SQL (sa  dbo@master)>

Also, same with sqsh:
# sqsh -S 192.168.68.139 -U "sa" -P "Password1"
sqsh-2.5.16.1 Copyright (C) 1995-2001 Scott C. Gray
Portions Copyright (C) 2004-2014 Michael Peppler and Martin Wesdorp
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
For more information type '\warranty'
1> SELECT SYSTEM_USER;
2> GO;
3> SELECT @@VERSION;
4> GO;

What's also weird is that statements executed from netexec (new crackmapexec) work!
# netexec mssql 192.168.68.139 -u 'sa' -p 'Password1' -q 'SELECT @@VERSION' --local-auth
MSSQL       192.168.68.139  1433   SQL02            [*] Windows 10 / Server 2019 Build 17763 (name:SQL02) (domain:VILNSEC.LOCAL)
MSSQL       192.168.68.139  1433   SQL02            [+] SQL02\sa:Password1 (Pwn3d!)
MSSQL       192.168.68.139  1433   SQL02            Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64)
    Oct  8 2022 05:58:25
    Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Additionally, If I was to use something like HeidiSQL to connect from a Windows machine, my statements work and execute.
What's the issue here? Is there some magic setting I need to set in order to allow executing basic queries? I want to be able to execute any SQL statement there is, even if its a low-priv user (any domain account)...
